# How come my "message.reply" is not working (Discord.JS)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I am learning discord.Js and I am trying to figure out why my message.reply function is not working. I created an event for the bot to listen to messages and when a message with the content of "hello" is sent it should reply with "hello buddy" here is the code:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new discord.Client({
    intents: []
    
});


client.login(process.env.TOKEN);


client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} has logged in`);
});


client.on('message', function(message){
    if(message.content === 'hello') {
        message.reply('hello buddy')
    }
});
```

The bot in discord has all the permissions required to send messages in the server I am testing it in.

Comment: Is the event firing at all? If not, it could be because it's deprecated. The documentation suggests using the [`messageCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate) event instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bot does not detect messages. You need `GUILDS` and `GUILD_MESSAGES` intents

```js
const client = new discord.Client({
    intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"]
})
```

Also, the `message` event is deprecated. Use `messageCreate` instead

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if(message.content === 'hello') {
        message.reply('hello buddy')
    }
})
```

Note that I used an arrow function. They are cleaner syntax and you should use them in callbacks